# Android: WebView - not getting Camera and Mic enabled for conference

Tags: android, webview, android-camera

We connect to https://meet.jit.si for video conference. If we use a chrome browser on Android device (tested on both Android 7 and 10), we are able to join with both Camera and Mic enabled. Able to turn them on and off as well. But if we try the same using a webview, we are not even getting a prompt from the website to allow access and get a "Failed to access camera/mic" error when trying to turn them on.

This is our code.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Getting runtime permission on load

```
    String[] permissions =
            {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
             Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
             Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
             Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
             Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            permissions,
            1010);
```

Loading the webpage into WebView

```
String url = "https://meet.jit.si/testingconf49854";
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings mWebSettings = webView.getSettings();
mWebSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
mWebSettings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
mWebSettings.setTextZoom(70);
mWebSettings.setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE );
mWebSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

Map<String, String> noCacheHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
noCacheHeaders.put("Pragma", "no-cache");
noCacheHeaders.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
webView.loadUrl(url, noCacheHeaders);
```

Please let us know what we are missing here. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After getting those permissions, you need to override `onPermissionRequest` in `WebChromeClient` like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  @Override
   public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
       request.grant(request.getResources());
}
});
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly on both Android 7 and 10. Thank you very much for the precise and prompt help.

Comment: works really well, almost spend many times searching for the answer, thank you very much

Comment: This is a good answer, but Android disagrees. See the documentation:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest

Comment: You need to grant access for each permission requested in accordance with the permissions of your application. You will have ANR if it happens that a certain WEB page of the server through HTML code requests access to resources that are not set in the Manifest file. You also know that the permissions from your Manifesto file must be approved in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it that way, work perfectly for me. This is my code:

```
   @Override
           public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request){
                String[] resources = request.getResources();
                
                switch (resources[0]){
                    case PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Audio Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE});
                    break;
                    case PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_MIDI_SYSEX:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MIDI Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_MIDI_SYSEX});
                    break;
                    case PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Encrypted media permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID});
                    break;
                    case PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Video Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
                    break;
                }
           }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a great answer, and it agrees with the recommendations of the people from Android. It is only necessary to execute the code in the UI.
See their documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest